# To prove an identity involving determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose, I have a $3 \times 6$ matrix of the form,

$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} \\
 a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6}\\
\end{array}
\right)=\left( a_1 \, a_2 \, a_3 \, a_4 \, a_5 \, a_6\right)$

where $a_i$ denotes a column matrix, and A is of rank 3.

Now, let me denote $A_{i,j,k}=( a_i \, a_j \, a_k)$.
Then, how can I prove the following identity?

$$\left|
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 |A_{4,2,3}| & |A_{5,2,3}| & |A_{6,2,3}| \\
 |A_{1,4,3}| & |A_{1,5,3}| & |A_{1,6,3}| \\
 |A_{1,2,4}| & |A_{1,2,5}| & |A_{1,2,6}| \\
\end{array}
\right|=\left| A_{1,2,3} \right|^2 \left| A_{4,5,6} \right|$$

I want an algebraic way to prove the above identity.
This question is a generalization of the results in ([How to prove the following Matrix Identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4248079/how-to-prove-the-following-matrix-identity/))
Any relevant references will be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\det A_{4,2,3} & \det A_{5,2,3} & \det A_{6,2,3}\\
\det A_{4,3,1} & \det A_{5,3,1} & \det A_{6,3,1}\\
\det A_{4,1,2} & \det A_{5,1,2} & \det A_{6,1,2}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2\times a_3 & a_3\times a_1 & a_1\times a_2
\end{pmatrix}^T
A_{4,5,6}
$$
So take determinant and recall the identity
$$
[\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c},\mathbf{c}\times\mathbf{a},\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}]=[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}]^2
$$
to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't figure out how to derive the second equation from the matrix form.

Comment: Can me please show me that or any relevant reference?

Comment: @Epsilon Which second equation?  The one with scalar triple product?

Comment: I mean this equation

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2\times a_3 & a_3\times a_1 & a_1\times a_2
\end{pmatrix}^T
A_{4,5,6}
$$

Comment: Going along the top row $(a_2\times a_3)^T$ of the $\begin{pmatrix}a_2\times a_3&\dots\end{pmatrix}^T$ and first column $a_4$ of $A_{4,5,6}$, for example, you have $a_4\cdot(a_2\times a_3)=\det A_{4,2,3}$.  Similarly the other entries.

Comment: Yes, I understand your logic.

Comment: I was wondering whether this alternative proof is correct or not.

As $A=(a_1 \, a_2\, a_3\, a_4\, a_5\, a_6)$ is a generic $3\times 6$ matrix with $Rank(A)=3$, can we not suppose $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ to be unit vectors? with no loss of generality. Such that $a_1=\delta_{i,1}$ , $a_2=\delta_{i,2}$ and $a_3=\delta_{i,3}$. Then, $|A_{1,2,3}|=1$ and using the fact that $|A_{4,2,3}|=(a_4)_1$, etc. Can we not prove the above identity? My main confusion is whether we can take $a_1 \,, a_2, \, a_3$ as I have taken without loss of generality.

Comment: Note rank(A) can't be more than 3.  If you want to take $A_{1,2,3}$ the identity properly, consider multiplying $A$ by $(A_{1,2,3})^{-1}$ on the left (and you need to deal with the case $A_{1,2,3}$ not invertible, there are various ways around this just pick one you are comfortable with -- density argument, explicit calculation for this case, etc.) and what effect it has on $\det A_{i,j,k}$ and what you need to prove.

Comment: Yes, I have added an answer based on the point you made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative proof:

With no loss of generality let me choose label $a_i$'s such that $|A_{1,2,3}|\neq 0$.

Then, I can write,

$$ A= (a_1 \, a_2 \, a_3 \, a_4 \, a_5 \, a_6)= (a_1 \, a_2 \, a_3) A'= A_{1,2,3}\, A'$$

where,

$$ A' =( I \, a'_4 \, a'_5 \, a'_6)$$

such that $I$ is a $3\times 3$ unit matrix, $a'_4=(a_1 \, a_2\, a_3)^{-1} a_4$ and similar expressions for $a'_5$ and $a'_6$.

Now, we note that

$$A_{i,j,k}=A_{1,2,3} \, A'_{i,j,k} $$
Therefore,
$$|A_{4,2,3}|=|A_{1,2,3}|\,\,|A'_{4,2,3}|=|A_{1,2,3}| (a'_4)_{11}$$
Similar identity gives us,
$$\left|
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 |A_{4,2,3}| & |A_{5,2,3}| & |A_{6,2,3}| \\
 |A_{1,4,3}| & |A_{1,5,3}| & |A_{1,6,3}| \\
 |A_{1,2,4}| & |A_{1,2,5}| & |A_{1,2,6}| \\
\end{array}
\right|=|A_{1,2,3}|^{3} |a'_4 \, a'_5 \, a'_6|=|A_{1,2,3}|^{3} A'_{4,5,6}=|A_{1,2,3}|^{2} A_{4,5,6}$$

Hence, proved!